# Make JFrame read-only

Tags: java, swing, jframe

Is there any way to convert a JFrame to read-only, similarly to `Collections.unmodifiableList()`?

I need to pass it as parameter to many classes, but I don't want them to close the window or do anything but consulting. Also I would need some custom methods to be available (because I'm extending JFrame).

(I don't mean disable all components, I mean you can't write on the object if you have a reference to it).

Comment: Why can't you just override the methods you don't want called and make them throw exceptions?

Comment: @cricket_007 because it is a JFrame. It has so many methods.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you want this. Are you shipping your GUI as part of some package you don't want external users to modify?

Comment: @cricket_007 no, it is just a matter of design. It is a window with some components inside that need to read information on it, but I don't want them (or anyone I give a reference) to do things over it but reading.

Comment: Then make a mental note to yourself not the call methods on the frame that'll modify it. Or simply don't pass the entire frame as a parameter

Comment: @cricket_007 mental notes doesn't work here. They can't be able to do anything. Is a must to be well designed.

Comment: Create a GUI model that holds the values displayed on the JFrame.  Pass an instance of the GUI model around to whatever part of your application needs the information.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: yours is the most robust solution and should be presented as an answer (so I can up-vote it).

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc: that sounds good. It is not what I was looking for but I guess it can do the job. Can you present it as a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that.  The proper solution is not to extend JFrame at all.  In general, you should never extend component classes to do things you can already do just by calling their public methods;  routine usage of a class like JFrame does not constitute a new type of JFrame, any more than putting different people in a Volkswagen qualifies it as a new type of car.

Instead, you should wrap the JFrame in a class which extends nothing<sup>†</sup>, and hide the JFrame in it.  Then you can expose only the methods you want to expose:

```
public class MyAppWindow {
    private final JFrame frame;

    private final JComponent frameContents;

    public MyAppWindow() {
        this.frame = new JFrame("My App");
        this.frameContents = new JPanel();
        // Set up frameContents here...
    }

    public void show() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hide() {
        frame.setVisible(false);
    }

    public void addField(Component field,
                         String labelText) {

        JLabel label = new JLabel(labelText);
        label.setLabelFor(field);

        // Create layout constraints for label here...

        frameContents.add(label, constraints);

        // Create layout constraints for field here...

        frameContents.add(field, constraints);
    }
}
```

<sup>†</sup> Technically, a class with no `extends` clause will inherit from Object.

Comment: Well, that is half the solution. The problem is that my objects must recieve (let's say) MyWindow for a matter of polymorphism. So it should be encapsulated in another MyWindow object, but then again they could do bad things with the container.

Comment: `"So it should be encapsulated in another MyWindow object, but then again they could do bad things with the container."` -- here's where it's time to use interfaces and the Decorator Pattern. Expose only the methods that you want exposed. 1+ to VGR.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solutions:

1. Make the components it holds "read-only", one way by making them all individually non-focusable.
2. I suppose you could recursively iterate through the container/component tree making all non-focusable
3. Cover the JFrame with a glasspane that blocks user input.

---

As a side recommendation:

> Also I would need some custom methods to be available (because I'm extending JFrame).

You may be painting yourself in a corner by having your class extend JFrame, forcing you to create and display JFrames, when often more flexibility is called for. In fact, I would venture that most of the Swing GUI code that I've created and that I've seen does **not** extend JFrame, and in fact it is rare that you'll ever want to do this. More commonly your GUI classes will be geared towards creating JPanels, which can then be placed into JFrames or JDialogs, or JTabbedPanes, or swapped via CardLayouts, wherever needed. This will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI coding.

Comment: I think I didn't explain well. I meant that other classes can't do anything if they have a reference to the JFrame, not disable components. I am not painting on the JFrame, I just have methods that access some data.

Comment: @Germán: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you've posted above. Could you tell me a little more of the details of your problem. Consider also editing your question and adding any important information to the question as well, so that others who might give good answers can read it and fully understand your problem.

Comment: I mean converting the object to read-only, so that you can't call to dispose() for example if you have a reference to the object. Something similar to `Collections.unmodifiableList()`.